# Avoid loading event chains in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in my code where many entities have async loading procedures and can't be used until these are complete. There are chains of these dependencies.
So `A->B->C` where A needs B needs C.

I have written code like

```
class B{
  constructor(callback){
    this.loaded=false
    this.load(callback)
  }
  load(callback){
    ...do stuff
    this.loaded=true
    callback()
  }
}

class A{
  constructor(){
    this.loaded=false
    this.b=new B(()=>{this.loaded=true})
  }
}
```

This seems really bad. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Sounds like you probably want a factory method (at least) that can then more freely return Promises that resolve with an instance. So you'd be able to do `B.create().then(newInstance => /* do something */)`. Although that doesn't solve the whole async initialisation roundabout, at least it makes it behave normally, instead of having `new` produce async behaviour and modifying the internals of the class to pass around callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is a bad practice to perform async task directly in constructor (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise)). With this taken in account, you can follow VLAZ advice and start using promises.

You would then have something like this:

```js
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.loaded = false
  }

  load() {
    return new Promise((resolve =>  {
      this.loaded = true;
      // do stuff
      return resolve()
    }))
  }
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.loaded = false
  }

  load() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.b = new B()
      this.loaded = true
      return resolve(this.b)
    })
  }
}

// Use it like this
const a = new A()

a.load()
  .then(b => b.load())
  .then(/* and so on */)
```